# Finding out my range

Tags: poker-tools

Is there a free software that can compute my range from my hand history and show  what I am playing from the various positions?

I am a beginner, so I don't feel quite ready to spring up for PokerTracker just yet, but I'd like to check what I am playing to see what kind of mistakes I make at the tables and see how I am perceived by people using HUDs.

Comment: Where are you getting you hand history.  You could write a program.

Comment: My hand history is stored in text format and I considered writing a small analytic program, but the time involved would be worth significantly more than the price of a PockerTracker license. 
Could still be fun to do, so I am bit on the fence about it. I am surprised there aren't already hundreds of freeware that do just that.

Comment: Well, are you looking to learn about all helpful ranges and chance of success in different scenarios?

Comment: Pokertracker does this. Look in the forums, as there are coded examples there.

Comment: @TobyBooth I understand, but I plan on buying it later on if I decide to take poker more seriously.

Comment: @river10 No. Many free software do that already. I want to find out the range I am actually playing, and assess the results. 
An issue is that probability of winning and earnings are not the same thing: AA beats everything else at least 3 to 1 as a starting hand, but it doesn't take down big pots, and depending on the flop, you can end up losing a lot of chips if you stick to your AA in the face of two pairs or better. So I'd like to assess what I am doing and what works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Poker-Co-Pilot (not entirely free, but does offer a free trial) does this pretty nicely not too complicated to work, shows your percentage opening from different positions and other information I use it for mac, not too sure if its for windows too.

Comment: OP asked for *free* software.

Comment: it has a free trial and it will give him exactly what he wants. and overview of his hands and positions that he's opening. @Daan

Comment: A free trial =/= free software. This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: He’s asking for free software to check his ranges, the free trial allows him to do this, he also mentions he’s not ready for poker tracker the free trail will last long enough to decide if he’s ready.@Daan. Also if you don’t like my answer instead of criticising it, how about you post a useful answer yourself.

Comment: Because I am looking for the same answer as OP. I have searched, but unfortunately didn't find any software that meets the requirements.

Comment: Lets not be pedantic, huh. A little flexibility goes a long way. I have edited the answer to be more detailed regarding the "free" aspect of the software.